Why OutOfMem error for Cassandra pod on Kubernetes despite sufficient RAM in worker node?
I am running a cassandra pod on a Kubernetes worker node named kworker4 which has 16 GB RAM and no other pod is running in that worker node. I am using bitnami/cassandra.
The memory and CPU usage is like below in the Kubernetes cluster.
NAME       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
kmaster    225m         2%     1672Mi          10%
kworker1   67m          0%     2499Mi          16%
kworker2   28m          0%     1834Mi          11%
kworker3   78m          0%     1487Mi          9%
kworker4   359m         4%     1988Mi          12%
kworker5   76m          0%     1244Mi          7%

When I set maxHeapSize: "2048M" in values.yaml of bitnami/cassandra helm chart, the cassandra-0 pod is starting up.
But when I set maxHeapSize: "4096M" in values.yaml of bitnami/cassandra helm chart, the cassandra-0 pod is not starting up although the worker node kworker4 is running on a machine that has 16 GB RAM and from the top command it is found that memory utilization is very low without the cassandra-0 pod.
what is the issue?
I checked the syslog of Ubuntu and found the following:
Jul 10 13:44:47 kworker4 systemd[1]: Started Session 66 of User kadmin.
Jul 10 13:49:37 kworker4 NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1720619377.9003] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): state changed new lease, address=10.227.25.233
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 kubelet[2861]: I0710 13:52:17.334274    2861 topology_manager.go:215] "Topology Admit Handler" podUID="45d3f529-6498-42a7-a26c-b255967b2533" podNamespace="default" podName="cassandra-0"
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 kubelet[2861]: E0710 13:52:17.334380    2861 cpu_manager.go:395] "RemoveStaleState: removing container" podUID="f2e22176-28e4-4a8f-87c1-2806a522832e" containerName="cassandra"
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 kubelet[2861]: I0710 13:52:17.334422    2861 memory_manager.go:354] "RemoveStaleState removing state" podUID="f2e22176-28e4-4a8f-87c1-2806a522832e" containerName="cassandra"
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 systemd[1]: Created slice libcontainer container kubepods-burstable-pod45d3f529_6498_42a7_a26c_b255967b2533.slice.
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 kubelet[2861]: I0710 13:52:17.519739    2861 reconciler_common.go:247] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"empty-dir\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/empty-dir/45d3f529-6498-42a7-a26c-b255967b2533-empty-dir\") pod \"cassandra-0\" (UID: \"45d3f529-6498-42a7-a26c-b255967b2533\") " pod="default/cassandra-0"
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 kubelet[2861]: I0710 13:52:17.519848    2861 reconciler_common.go:247] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"data-cassandra-0\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/local-volume/data-cassandra-0\") pod \"cassandra-0\" (UID: \"45d3f529-6498-42a7-a26c-b255967b2533\") " pod="default/cassandra-0"
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 kubelet[2861]: I0710 13:52:17.621078    2861 operation_generator.go:664] "MountVolume.MountDevice succeeded for volume \"data-cassandra-0\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/local-volume/data-cassandra-0\") pod \"cassandra-0\" (UID: \"45d3f529-6498-42a7-a26c-b255967b2533\") device mount path \"/mnt/local-persistent-volumes/data-cassandra-0\"" pod="default/cassandra-0"
Jul 10 13:52:17 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:17.946171772Z" level=info msg="RunPodSandbox for &PodSandboxMetadata{Name:cassandra-0,Uid:45d3f529-6498-42a7-a26c-b255967b2533,Namespace:default,Attempt:0,}"
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 networkd-dispatcher[957]: WARNING:Unknown index 39 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.055341] weave: port 2(vethwepl9deef76) entered blocking state
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.055350] weave: port 2(vethwepl9deef76) entered disabled state
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.055607] device vethwepl9deef76 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1720619538.4870] manager: (vethwepg9deef76): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/37)
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 systemd-udevd[293361]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1720619538.5216] manager: (vethwepl9deef76): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/38)
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 networkd-dispatcher[957]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 39 seen even after reload
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 networkd-dispatcher[957]: WARNING:Unknown index 39 seen, reloading interface list
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.097012] eth0: renamed from vethwepg9deef76
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 systemd-networkd[921]: vethwepl9deef76: Link UP
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 networkd-dispatcher[957]: ERROR:Unknown interface index 39 seen even after reload
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 systemd-networkd[921]: vethwepl9deef76: Gained carrier
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 NetworkManager[938]: <info>  [1720619538.5638] device (vethwepl9deef76): carrier: link connected
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.132876] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.132910] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethwepl9deef76: link becomes ready
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.132944] weave: port 2(vethwepl9deef76) entered blocking state
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 kernel: [111165.132947] weave: port 2(vethwepl9deef76) entered forwarding state
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T19:22:18.687796519+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T19:22:18.687933851+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T19:22:18.687970510+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T19:22:18.688176283+05:30" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.pause\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 9deef764a0e07a31d7812c23efa211c36d9a74b470c5c07b9b6e0586dade5750.
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:18.770045331Z" level=info msg="RunPodSandbox for &PodSandboxMetadata{Name:cassandra-0,Uid:45d3f529-6498-42a7-a26c-b255967b2533,Namespace:default,Attempt:0,} returns sandbox id \"9deef764a0e07a31d7812c23efa211c36d9a74b470c5c07b9b6e0586dade5750\""
Jul 10 13:52:18 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:18.790190901Z" level=info msg="CreateContainer within sandbox \"9deef764a0e07a31d7812c23efa211c36d9a74b470c5c07b9b6e0586dade5750\" for container &ContainerMetadata{Name:cassandra,Attempt:0,}"
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:19.007961508Z" level=info msg="CreateContainer within sandbox \"9deef764a0e07a31d7812c23efa211c36d9a74b470c5c07b9b6e0586dade5750\" for &ContainerMetadata{Name:cassandra,Attempt:0,} returns container id \"2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752\""
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:19.008715302Z" level=info msg="StartContainer for \"2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752\""
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 systemd[1]: Started libcontainer container 2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752.
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:19.141433055Z" level=info msg="StartContainer for \"2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752\" returns successfully"
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 avahi-daemon[935]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface vethwepl9deef76.IPv6 with address fe80::5cae:7cff:fe8b:e880.
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 avahi-daemon[935]: New relevant interface vethwepl9deef76.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 systemd-networkd[921]: vethwepl9deef76: Gained IPv6LL
Jul 10 13:52:19 kworker4 avahi-daemon[935]: Registering new address record for fe80::5cae:7cff:fe8b:e880 on vethwepl9deef76.*.
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 systemd[1]: cri-containerd-2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752.scope: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800862] java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xcc0(GFP_KERNEL), order=0, oom_score_adj=869
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800866] CPU: 3 PID: 293719 Comm: java Not tainted 5.15.0-113-generic #123-Ubuntu
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800868] Hardware name: LENOVO 20Q6S2WR01/20Q6S2WR01, BIOS R0ZET47W (1.25 ) 01/27/2021
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800869] Call Trace:
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800870]  <TASK>
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800872]  show_stack+0x52/0x5c
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800875]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800878]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800878]  dump_header+0x53/0x228
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800881]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800882]  out_of_memory+0x106/0x2e0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800885]  mem_cgroup_out_of_memory+0x13f/0x160
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800888]  try_charge_memcg+0x687/0x740
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800889]  charge_memcg+0x45/0xb0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800890]  __mem_cgroup_charge+0x2d/0x90
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800892]  do_anonymous_page+0x114/0x3c0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800893]  handle_pte_fault+0x20a/0x240
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800895]  __handle_mm_fault+0x405/0x6f0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800897]  handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0x2c0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800898]  do_user_addr_fault+0x1c9/0x670
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800901]  exc_page_fault+0x77/0x170
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800902]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800905] RIP: 0033:0x7ff983e72220
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800907] Code: 03 48 8d 05 96 57 8f 00 8b 13 89 10 e9 6e ff ff ff 90 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 48 39 f7 48 89 e5 73 12 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 <c6> 07 00 48 01 d7 48 39 fe 77 f5 5d c3 90 66 90 55 45 0f b6 c9 48
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800908] RSP: 002b:00007ff9831fdc00 EFLAGS: 00010206
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800909] RAX: 0000000000001000 RBX: 00007ff982c8f638 RCX: 00007ff9853208a3
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800911] RDX: 0000000000001000 RSI: 0000000800000000 RDI: 00000007bee67000
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800911] RBP: 00007ff9831fdc00 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 00000000f0000000
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800912] R10: 0000000000000032 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000710000000
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800913] R13: 00000000f0000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000800000000
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800915]  </TASK>
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800916] memory: usage 3145728kB, limit 3145728kB, failcnt 56
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800917] swap: usage 0kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800918] Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod45d3f529_6498_42a7_a26c_b255967b2533.slice:
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] anon 3213541376
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] file 90112
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] kernel_stack 65536
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] pagetables 6504448
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] percpu 47296
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] sock 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] shmem 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] file_mapped 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] file_dirty 90112
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] file_writeback 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] swapcached 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] anon_thp 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] file_thp 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] shmem_thp 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] inactive_anon 3213463552
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] active_anon 12288
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] inactive_file 49152
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] active_file 40960
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] unevictable 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] slab_reclaimable 736952
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] slab_unreclaimable 146752
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] slab 883704
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] workingset_refault_anon 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] workingset_refault_file 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] workingset_activate_anon 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] workingset_activate_file 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800926] workingset_restore_anon 0
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800927] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800928] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800928] [ 293427] 65535 293427      249        1    28672        0          -998 pause
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800931] [ 293470]  1001 293470  1164985   787981  6496256        0           869 java
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800933] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=cri-containerd-2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod45d3f529_6498_42a7_a26c_b255967b2533.slice,task_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod45d3f529_6498_42a7_a26c_b255967b2533.slice/cri-containerd-2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752.scope,task=java,pid=293470,uid=1001
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800941] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 293470 (java) total-vm:4659940kB, anon-rss:3138004kB, file-rss:13920kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1001 pgtables:6344kB oom_score_adj:869
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800991] Tasks in /kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pod45d3f529_6498_42a7_a26c_b255967b2533.slice/cri-containerd-2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752.scope are going to be killed due to memory.oom.group set
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 kernel: [111176.800995] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 293719 (java) total-vm:4659940kB, anon-rss:3138176kB, file-rss:14392kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1001 pgtables:6344kB oom_score_adj:869
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:30.229521112Z" level=info msg="TaskOOM event container_id:\"2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752\""
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 systemd[1]: cri-containerd-2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 systemd[1]: cri-containerd-2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752.scope: Consumed 1.333s CPU time.
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 systemd[1]: run-containerd-io.containerd.runtime.v2.task-k8s.io-2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752-rootfs.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:30.859741550Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752 namespace=k8s.io
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:30.859867500Z" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752 namespace=k8s.io
Jul 10 13:52:30 kworker4 containerd[1054]: time="2024-07-10T13:52:30.859893980Z" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim" namespace=k8s.io
Jul 10 13:52:31 kworker4 kubelet[2861]: I0710 13:52:31.580868    2861 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="2cb8ea27c355aae5a717ce8c7ffab53f627ac0ce73f7349a0a0c009c6bb80752"


Could you provide output from command kubectl describe po cassandra-0 when it is not starting? You should see Events there that may tell more why k8s is not able to start this pod. My current guess is that you have other pods on kworker4 that have some specific request on memory and your pod is not starting since this resource is already reserve for other workloads.

Please find below the output of describe pod command.
Normal   Started    15s (x2 over 28s)  kubelet            Started container cassandra
Warning  BackOff    3s                 kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container cassandra in pod cassandra-0_default(420c0057-14ff-435f-9d23-5dd199278465)

In the describe pod output I found below limits:
    Limits:
      cpu:                1500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             3Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                1
      ephemeral-storage:  50Mi
      memory:             2Gi


I set below values in values.yaml, but got same error.
resourcesPreset: "large"
## @param resources Set container requests and limits for different resources like CPU or memory (essential for production workloads)
## Example:
resources:
   requests:
     cpu: 3
     memory: 4096Mi
   limits:
     cpu: 3
     memory: 4096Mi
##
resources:


It would be good also to have kubectl logs cassandra-0. From what you describe your maxHeapSize settings was bigger than pod limit for memory and probably due to that pod was failing to start. Could you add following resources values to your helm and redeploy app
resources:
requests:
cpu: 2
memory: 5Gi
limits:
cpu: 3
memory: 6Gi

Thanks very much! I set the resources as suggested and the cassandra-0 pod started successfully. Please post your suggestion as Answer.

Following logs from kubectl describe po cassandra-0 command suggest that pod is able to start but with some error
Normal Started 15s (x2 over 28s) kubelet Started container cassandra 
Warning BackOff 3s kubelet Back-off restarting failed container cassandra in pod cassandra-0_default

This error is caused by mismatch in memory maxHeapSize and resources allocation for pod.
Please edit your helm values file and allocate following resources
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: 2
    memory: 5Gi
  limits:
    cpu: 3
    memory: 6Gi

This should provide enough memory for cassandra pod.
